# microsoft exchange removal. Is it possible?

Tags: windows, exchange, microsoft

I have a 2013 server with exchange installed that I want exchange removed, I only use this server for it's active directory function to control login to connected pc's and as a file server.  I no longer use or want the email services, How can I remove exchange without causing a problem with active directory? Or is it even possible to do it without doing a fresh install and not adding exchange?

Comment: Just remove your databases, adressbooks and connectors, then start uninstalling.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible; for example, it is referenced in the Microsoft document [How and when to decommission your on-premises Exchange servers in a hybrid deployment](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/decommission-on-premises-exchange).

That being said, that lengthy document mostly describes how to ensure that your mail configuration is properly migrated to another server, and the final step is:

> 20. You can now safely uninstall Exchange from the on-premises servers.

Actually uninstalling is apparently an exercise left to the reader!  [This post at social.technet](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/09d2e0ca-7553-48ab-a9ed-4d0ff4e2e543/correctly-uninstall-exchange-2013?forum=exchangesvrdeploy) also includes disentanglement steps and ends with:

> Finally, you can uninstall Exchange 2013 from Add/Remove Programs or
>   PowerShell with below command:
>
> `Setup /Mode:Uninstall /iacceptexchangeserverlicenseterms`